# gae urlfetch for some urls returns the mobile version of the url

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http, urlfetch

I'm using a simple urlfetch call in Google App Engine to retrieve pages from a website.

The weird thing is that the pages that are returned are always the "m.website.com" mobile version.

I changed the user agent of the fetch() but nothing seems to change this behavior. Does anyone know whether there is a way to ensure the desktop/laptop web version of the page is returned?

Sample code below:

```
    url = "http://www.example.com/a-page"
    urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(25)
    page = urlfetch.fetch(url, headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0"})
    if page.status_code != 200:
        logging.info("alert: URL status code: {}, trying to fetch page: {}".format(page.status_code, url))
    if page:
        self.response.write("\n{}".format(page.status_code))
        self.response.write("\n{}".format(page.final_url))
        self.response.write("\n{}".format(page.headers))
        self.response.write("\n{}".format(page.header_msg))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)
        self.response.write("\n{}".format(soup.prettify(encoding="utf-8")))
```

the result always takes the first page, "www.example.com/a-page", does a redirect and returns "m.example.com/mobile-version-of-a-page"...

Comment: did you try removing user-agent altogether?

Comment: hmm...according to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/#Python_Request_headers

`User-Agent. This header can be modified but App Engine will append an identifier string to allow servers to identify App Engine requests. The appended string has the format "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine; appid: APPID)", where APPID is your app's identifier.`

Comment: good idea - but I just tried it and get the same result. For some reason I guess the user-agent that Google appends by default, even  though there is nothing to indicate "mobile", gets interpreted by this website as a request from a mobile device...